# script lost the permissions to modify ScriptDb

Tags: google-apps-script

Hi about an hour ago and while editing some scripts, all those scripts lost their permission to save or delete from the db. I tried to reauthorize them and although i tried a number of things i could not get the authorization prompt to show. I keep getting the following error messages:

You do not have permission to call remove.

You do not have permission to call save.

Additionally at that time i noticed that on the upper right corner of the script editor was a notification for 3 more viewers (all showing my username). I have open only one browser and one instance of the editor but the notification is still there.

Any suggestion?

(P.S. on all other scripts there is none of these "problems")

Answer (score 0):

I saved a new version of my db library, reauthorized the db library (finally), updated the libraries on the other scripts, reauthorized the scripts and all seem to be going well. The funny thing is that i hadn't touched my db library at all before the problem showed up.